# Jquery removeClass with css animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following css rule for table row background,

```
tr.unread {
    background:rgba(237, 239, 245, 0.70) none repeat scroll 0 0;
   -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
   -o-transition: background 1s linear;
   transition: background 1s linear;
 }
```

I want to remove the `.unread` class from `tr` with fading out animation (without Javascript / Jquery if possible). But it just removes the class without any animation.

Javascript: `$('tr.unread').removeClass('unread');`

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Are you using jquery-ui?

Comment: No. Using jquery only.

Comment: absolutely no need for JQueryUI for this, add and remove class is all you should be doing with the js

Answer (score 4):

Transition rules must be defined on the `tr` element:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('tr.unread').removeClass('unread');
});
```

```css
tr {
    -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background 1s linear;
    transition: background 1s linear;
}
tr.unread {
    background: rgba(237, 239, 245, 0.70) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td>
            <td>Table Cell 1</td>
            <td>Table Cell 2</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread">
        <td>
            <td>Table Cell 1</td>
            <td>Table Cell 2</td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button>Mark read</button>
```

Comment: Cool. But any other solutions except adding `animation` property in `tr` element. Because I have many other tables in other pages and I don't want to affect them.

Comment: You should use another class. Just make something like **animated.unread** instead of **tr.unread** and put animation to **animated**.

Comment: I mean is there any way except altering original `tr` rule ?

Comment: You can limit this behavior for one table with some class. Like `<table class="messages">` and in CSS: `.messages tr {-webkit-transition: ...}`

Comment: you can just add a class `message` then add and remove the `unread` class from that class, no need to mention HTML structure at all in the css or the jquery, then, when you apply it elsewhere or stop using tables it will still just work :-)